# FFMPEG merging audio and video to get resulting video

Tags: audio, video, merge, ffmpeg

I need to merge audio and video using ffmpeg so that, it should result in a video with the same duration as of audio.

I have tried 2 commands for that requirement in my linux terminal. Both the commands work for a few of the input videos; but for some other input_videos, they produce output same as the input video, the audio doesn't get merged.

The commands, I have tried are -

> ffmpeg -i wonders.mp4 -i Carefull.mp3 -c copy testvid.mp4

and

> ffmpeg -i wonders.mp4 -i Carefull.mp3 -strict -2 testvid.mp4

and

> ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict
>   experimental output.mp4

and these are my input videos -

> 1. samplevid.mp4
>
> https://vid.me/z44E
>
> duration - 28 seconds
>
> size - 1.1 MB
>
> status - working

And

> 2. wonders.mp4
>
> https://vid.me/gyyB
>
> duration - 97 seconds
>
> size - 96 MB
>
> status - not working

I have observed that *the large size* (more than 2MB) of the input video is probably the issue.

But, still I want the fix.

Comment: you actually want to merge two videos with one Audio ?

Comment: nope, I just gave the example. I wanted to merge 1 video and 1 audio.

Comment: "ffmpeg -i video -i yourAudio -vcodec copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 ResultPath" 
use this if you want one audio and one Video

Comment: I used it in C# Coding it works fine for me hope it will help